# Facing issue while uploading trivia question sheet on action on google

Tags: actions-on-google

@ActionsOnGoogle [actions-on-google]
 , I am trying to create a quiz using actions on Google but always getting error while uploading my questions sheet. Getting below error, could u please assist, I am sure the questions I am uploading are original and not copied

[image]

Comment: That's not related to programming...

Comment: Where can i ask question like this ? Any idea? I posted the same on twitter handle, but didnt get any reply. :(

Comment: It looks like they were unable to determine the format. Try with a new spreadsheet.

Comment: I am updating the template sheet provided by them. Tried multiple times from laptop,  mobile its not working at all. Every time same error